Apache Spark getting janino compiler exception
Spark codegen is failing to compile the code. I'm using Spark 3.3.2.
Getting the below exception
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 109, Column 1: Cannot determine simple type name "com"
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:12021)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6850)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6620)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6633)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6633)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6633)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6633)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getType2(UnitCompiler.java:6599)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$14300(UnitCompiler.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$1.visitReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6502)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22$1.visitReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:6497)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$ReferenceType.accept(Java.java:4134)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22.visitType(UnitCompiler.java:6497)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$22.visitType(UnitCompiler.java:6490)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$ReferenceType.accept(Java.java:4133)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getType(UnitCompiler.java:6490)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getLocalVariable(UnitCompiler.java:2617)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:3691)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$5800(UnitCompiler.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitLocalVariableDeclarationStatement(UnitCompiler.java:3574)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitLocalVariableDeclarationStatement(UnitCompiler.java:3542)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$LocalVariableDeclarationStatement.accept(Java.java:3712)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:3541)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:3598)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$4700(UnitCompiler.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitBlock(UnitCompiler.java:3560)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitBlock(UnitCompiler.java:3542)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Block.accept(Java.java:2969)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:3541)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.buildLocalVariableMap(UnitCompiler.java:3604)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$4800(UnitCompiler.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitDoStatement(UnitCompiler.java:3561)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$12.visitDoStatement(UnitCompiler.java:3542)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$DoStatement.accept(Java.java:3664)


Code that is generated by the code gen is as below(code snippet).
    /* 001 */ public Object generate(Object[] references) {
    /* 002 */   return new GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(references);
    /* 003 */ }
    /* 004 */
    /* 005 */ // codegenStageId=1
    /* 006 */ final class GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1 extends org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator {
    /* 007 */   private Object[] references;
    /* 008 */   private scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs;
    /* 009 */   private scala.collection.Iterator inputadapter_input_0;
    /* 010 */   private org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance kryoSerializer;
    /* 011 */   private boolean filter_resultIsNull_0;
    /* 012 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_0;
    /* 013 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_1;
    /* 014 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_2;
    /* 015 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_3;
    /* 016 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_4;
    /* 017 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_5;
    /* 018 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_6;
    /* 019 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_7;
    /* 020 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_8;
    /* 021 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_9;
    /* 022 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_10;
    /* 023 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_11;
    /* 024 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_12;
    /* 025 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_13;
    /* 026 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_14;
    /* 027 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_15;
    /* 028 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_16;
    /* 029 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_17;
    /* 030 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_18;
    /* 031 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_19;
    /* 032 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_20;
    /* 033 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_21;
    /* 034 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_22;
    /* 035 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_23;
    /* 036 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_24;
    /* 037 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_25;
    /* 038 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_26;
    /* 039 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_27;
    /* 040 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_28;
    /* 041 */   private int serializefromobject_argValue_29;
    /* 042 */   private com.testing.events.events.TrackingEvent[] deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_1 = new com.testing.events.events.TrackingEvent[1];
    /* 043 */   private java.lang.String[] deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0 = new java.lang.String[22];
    /* 044 */   private scala.Tuple2[] filter_mutableStateArray_0 = new scala.Tuple2[2];
    /* 045 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter[] deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_2 = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter[6];
    /* 046 */
    /* 047 */   public GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(Object[] references) {
    /* 048 */     this.references = references;
    /* 049 */   }
    /* 050 */
    /* 051 */   public void init(int index, scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs) {
    /* 052 */     partitionIndex = index;
    /* 053 */     this.inputs = inputs;
    /* 054 */     inputadapter_input_0 = inputs[0];
    /* 055 */
    /* 056 */     kryoSerializer = (org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance) org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.SerializerSupport$.MODULE$.newSerializer(true);
    /* 057 */
    /* 058 */     deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_2[0] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 32);
    /* 059 */     deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_2[1] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 32);
    /* 060 */     deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_2[2] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 32);
    /* 061 */     deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_2[3] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 32);
    /* 062 */     deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_2[4] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 32);
    /* 063 */     deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_2[5] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(31, 672);
    /* 064 */
    /* 065 */   }
    /* 066 */
    /* 067 */   private void mapelements_doConsume_0(scala.Tuple2 mapelements_expr_0_0, boolean mapelements_exprIsNull_0_0) throws java.io.IOException {
    /* 068 */     boolean mapelements_isNull_1 = true;
    /* 069 */     org.apache.spark.sql.Row mapelements_value_1 = null;
    /* 070 */     filter_mutableStateArray_0[1] = mapelements_expr_0_0;
    /* 071 */
    /* 072 */     mapelements_isNull_1 = false;
    /* 073 */     if (!mapelements_isNull_1) {
    /* 074 */       Object mapelements_funcResult_0 = null;
    /* 075 */
    /* 076 */       try {
    /* 077 */         mapelements_funcResult_0 = ((org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction) references[2] /* literal */).call(filter_mutableStateArray_0[1]);
    /* 078 */       } catch (Exception e) {
    /* 079 */         org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.throwException(e);
    /* 080 */       }
    /* 081 */
    /* 082 */       if (mapelements_funcResult_0 != null) {
    /* 083 */         mapelements_value_1 = (org.apache.spark.sql.Row) mapelements_funcResult_0;
    /* 084 */       } else {
    /* 085 */         mapelements_isNull_1 = true;
    /* 086 */       }
    /* 087 */
    /* 088 */     }
    /* 089 */
    /* 090 */     serializefromobject_doConsume_0(mapelements_value_1, mapelements_isNull_1);
    /* 091 */
    /* 092 */   }
    /* 093 */
    /* 094 */   private void deserializetoobject_doConsume_0(InternalRow inputadapter_row_0, UTF8String deserializetoobject_expr_0_0, boolean deserializetoobject_exprIsNull_0_0, byte[] deserializetoobject_expr_1_0, boolean deserializetoobject_exprIsNull_1_0) throws java.io.IOException {
    /* 095 */     do {
    /* 096 */       boolean deserializetoobject_isNull_1 = true;
    /* 097 */       java.lang.String deserializetoobject_value_1 = null;
    /* 098 */       if (!deserializetoobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 099 */         deserializetoobject_isNull_1 = false;
    /* 100 */         if (!deserializetoobject_isNull_1) {
    /* 101 */           Object deserializetoobject_funcResult_0 = null;
    /* 102 */           deserializetoobject_funcResult_0 = deserializetoobject_expr_0_0.toString();
    /* 103 */           deserializetoobject_value_1 = (java.lang.String) deserializetoobject_funcResult_0;
    /* 104 */
    /* 105 */         }
    /* 106 */       }
    /* 107 */       deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[0] = deserializetoobject_value_1;
    /* 108 */
    /* 109 */       final com.testing.events.events.TrackingEvent deserializetoobject_value_3 =
    /* 110 */       deserializetoobject_exprIsNull_1_0 ? null : (com.testing.events.events.TrackingEvent) kryoSerializer.deserialize(java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(deserializetoobject_expr_1_0), null);
    /* 111 */       deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_1[0] = deserializetoobject_value_3;
    /* 112 */
    /* 113 */       final scala.Tuple2 deserializetoobject_value_0 = false ?
    /* 114 */       null : new scala.Tuple2(deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[0], deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_1[0]);
    /* 115 */
    /* 116 */       boolean filter_isNull_0 = true;
    /* 117 */       boolean filter_value_0 = false;
    /* 118 */       filter_resultIsNull_0 = false;
    /* 119 */
    /* 120 */       if (!filter_resultIsNull_0) {
    /* 121 */         filter_resultIsNull_0 = false;
    /* 122 */         filter_mutableStateArray_0[0] = deserializetoobject_value_0;
    /* 123 */       }
    /* 124 */
    /* 125 */       filter_isNull_0 = filter_resultIsNull_0;
    /* 126 */       if (!filter_isNull_0) {
    /* 127 */         try {
    /* 128 */           filter_value_0 = ((org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction) references[1] /* literal */).call(filter_mutableStateArray_0[0]);
    /* 129 */         } catch (Exception e) {
    /* 130 */           org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.throwException(e);
    /* 131 */         }
    /* 132 */
    /* 133 */       }
    /* 134 */       if (filter_isNull_0 || !filter_value_0) continue;
    /* 135 */
    /* 136 */       ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[0] /* numOutputRows */).add(1);
    /* 137 */
    /* 138 */       mapelements_doConsume_0(deserializetoobject_value_0, false);
    /* 139 */
    /* 140 */     } while(false);
    /* 141 */
    /* 142 */   }
    /* 143 */
    /* 144 */   private void serializefromobject_doConsume_0(org.apache.spark.sql.Row serializefromobject_expr_0_0, boolean serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) throws java.io.IOException {
    /* 145 */     if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 146 */       throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[3] /* errMsg */));
    /* 147 */     }
    /* 148 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_2 = true;
    /* 149 */     boolean serializefromobject_value_2 = false;
    /* 150 */     serializefromobject_argValue_0 = 0;
    /* 151 */
    /* 152 */     serializefromobject_isNull_2 = false;
    /* 153 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_2) {
    /* 154 */       serializefromobject_value_2 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(serializefromobject_argValue_0);
    /* 155 */     }
    /* 156 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_1 = false;
    /* 157 */     UTF8String serializefromobject_value_1 = null;
    /* 158 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_2 && serializefromobject_value_2) {
    /* 159 */       serializefromobject_isNull_1 = true;
    /* 160 */       serializefromobject_value_1 = ((UTF8String)null);
    /* 161 */     } else {
    /* 162 */       if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 163 */         throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[6] /* errMsg */));
    /* 164 */       }
    /* 165 */
    /* 166 */       if (false) {
    /* 167 */         throw QueryExecutionErrors.inputExternalRowCannotBeNullError();
    /* 168 */       }
    /* 169 */
    /* 170 */       if (serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(0)) {
    /* 171 */         throw new RuntimeException(((java.lang.String) references[5] /* errMsg */));
    /* 172 */       }
    /* 173 */
    /* 174 */       final Object serializefromobject_value_9 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.get(0);
    /* 175 */       java.lang.String serializefromobject_value_8 = null;
    /* 176 */       if (!false) {
    /* 177 */         if (serializefromobject_value_9 instanceof java.lang.String) {
    /* 178 */           serializefromobject_value_8 = (java.lang.String) serializefromobject_value_9;
    /* 179 */         } else {
    /* 180 */           throw new RuntimeException(serializefromobject_value_9.getClass().getName() + ((java.lang.String) references[4] /* errMsg */));
    /* 181 */         }
    /* 182 */       }
    /* 183 */       deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[1] = serializefromobject_value_8;
    /* 184 */
    /* 185 */       UTF8String serializefromobject_value_7 = null;
    /* 186 */       if (!false) {
    /* 187 */         serializefromobject_value_7 = org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromString(deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[1]);
    /* 188 */       }
    /* 189 */       serializefromobject_isNull_1 = false;
    /* 190 */       serializefromobject_value_1 = serializefromobject_value_7;
    /* 191 */     }
    /* 192 */     if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 193 */       throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[7] /* errMsg */));
    /* 194 */     }
    /* 195 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_13 = true;
    /* 196 */     boolean serializefromobject_value_13 = false;
    /* 197 */     serializefromobject_argValue_1 = 1;
    /* 198 */
    /* 199 */     serializefromobject_isNull_13 = false;
    /* 200 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_13) {
    /* 201 */       serializefromobject_value_13 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(serializefromobject_argValue_1);
    /* 202 */     }
    /* 203 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_12 = false;
    /* 204 */     UTF8String serializefromobject_value_12 = null;
    /* 205 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_13 && serializefromobject_value_13) {
    /* 206 */       serializefromobject_isNull_12 = true;
    /* 207 */       serializefromobject_value_12 = ((UTF8String)null);
    /* 208 */     } else {
    /* 209 */       if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 210 */         throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[10] /* errMsg */));
    /* 211 */       }
    /* 212 */
    /* 213 */       if (false) {
    /* 214 */         throw QueryExecutionErrors.inputExternalRowCannotBeNullError();
    /* 215 */       }
    /* 216 */
    /* 217 */       if (serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(1)) {
    /* 218 */         throw new RuntimeException(((java.lang.String) references[9] /* errMsg */));
    /* 219 */       }
    /* 220 */
    /* 221 */       final Object serializefromobject_value_20 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.get(1);
    /* 222 */       java.lang.String serializefromobject_value_19 = null;
    /* 223 */       if (!false) {
    /* 224 */         if (serializefromobject_value_20 instanceof java.lang.String) {
    /* 225 */           serializefromobject_value_19 = (java.lang.String) serializefromobject_value_20;
    /* 226 */         } else {
    /* 227 */           throw new RuntimeException(serializefromobject_value_20.getClass().getName() + ((java.lang.String) references[8] /* errMsg */));
    /* 228 */         }
    /* 229 */       }
    /* 230 */       deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[2] = serializefromobject_value_19;
    /* 231 */
    /* 232 */       UTF8String serializefromobject_value_18 = null;
    /* 233 */       if (!false) {
    /* 234 */         serializefromobject_value_18 = org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromString(deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[2]);
    /* 235 */       }
    /* 236 */       serializefromobject_isNull_12 = false;
    /* 237 */       serializefromobject_value_12 = serializefromobject_value_18;
    /* 238 */     }
    /* 239 */     if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 240 */       throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[11] /* errMsg */));
    /* 241 */     }
    /* 242 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_24 = true;
    /* 243 */     boolean serializefromobject_value_24 = false;
    /* 244 */     serializefromobject_argValue_2 = 2;
    /* 245 */
    /* 246 */     serializefromobject_isNull_24 = false;
    /* 247 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_24) {
    /* 248 */       serializefromobject_value_24 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(serializefromobject_argValue_2);
    /* 249 */     }
    /* 250 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_23 = false;
    /* 251 */     UTF8String serializefromobject_value_23 = null;
    /* 252 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_24 && serializefromobject_value_24) {
    /* 253 */       serializefromobject_isNull_23 = true;
    /* 254 */       serializefromobject_value_23 = ((UTF8String)null);
    /* 255 */     } else {
    /* 256 */       if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 257 */         throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[14] /* errMsg */));
    /* 258 */       }
    /* 259 */
    /* 260 */       if (false) {
    /* 261 */         throw QueryExecutionErrors.inputExternalRowCannotBeNullError();
    /* 262 */       }
    /* 263 */
    /* 264 */       if (serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(2)) {
    /* 265 */         throw new RuntimeException(((java.lang.String) references[13] /* errMsg */));
    /* 266 */       }
    /* 267 */
    /* 268 */       final Object serializefromobject_value_31 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.get(2);
    /* 269 */       java.lang.String serializefromobject_value_30 = null;
    /* 270 */       if (!false) {
    /* 271 */         if (serializefromobject_value_31 instanceof java.lang.String) {
    /* 272 */           serializefromobject_value_30 = (java.lang.String) serializefromobject_value_31;
    /* 273 */         } else {
    /* 274 */           throw new RuntimeException(serializefromobject_value_31.getClass().getName() + ((java.lang.String) references[12] /* errMsg */));
    /* 275 */         }
    /* 276 */       }
    /* 277 */       deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[3] = serializefromobject_value_30;
    /* 278 */
    /* 279 */       UTF8String serializefromobject_value_29 = null;
    /* 280 */       if (!false) {
    /* 281 */         serializefromobject_value_29 = org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromString(deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[3]);
    /* 282 */       }
    /* 283 */       serializefromobject_isNull_23 = false;
    /* 284 */       serializefromobject_value_23 = serializefromobject_value_29;
    /* 285 */     }
    /* 286 */     if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 287 */       throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[15] /* errMsg */));
    /* 288 */     }
    /* 289 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_35 = true;
    /* 290 */     boolean serializefromobject_value_35 = false;
    /* 291 */     serializefromobject_argValue_3 = 3;
    /* 292 */
    /* 293 */     serializefromobject_isNull_35 = false;
    /* 294 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_35) {
    /* 295 */       serializefromobject_value_35 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(serializefromobject_argValue_3);
    /* 296 */     }
    /* 297 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_34 = false;
    /* 298 */     UTF8String serializefromobject_value_34 = null;
    /* 299 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_35 && serializefromobject_value_35) {
    /* 300 */       serializefromobject_isNull_34 = true;
    /* 301 */       serializefromobject_value_34 = ((UTF8String)null);
    /* 302 */     } else {
    /* 303 */       if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 304 */         throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[18] /* errMsg */));
    /* 305 */       }
    /* 306 */
    /* 307 */       if (false) {
    /* 308 */         throw QueryExecutionErrors.inputExternalRowCannotBeNullError();
    /* 309 */       }
    /* 310 */
    /* 311 */       if (serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(3)) {
    /* 312 */         throw new RuntimeException(((java.lang.String) references[17] /* errMsg */));
    /* 313 */       }
    /* 314 */
    /* 315 */       final Object serializefromobject_value_42 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.get(3);
    /* 316 */       java.lang.String serializefromobject_value_41 = null;
    /* 317 */       if (!false) {
    /* 318 */         if (serializefromobject_value_42 instanceof java.lang.String) {
    /* 319 */           serializefromobject_value_41 = (java.lang.String) serializefromobject_value_42;
    /* 320 */         } else {
    /* 321 */           throw new RuntimeException(serializefromobject_value_42.getClass().getName() + ((java.lang.String) references[16] /* errMsg */));
    /* 322 */         }
    /* 323 */       }
    /* 324 */       deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[4] = serializefromobject_value_41;
    /* 325 */
    /* 326 */       UTF8String serializefromobject_value_40 = null;
    /* 327 */       if (!false) {
    /* 328 */         serializefromobject_value_40 = org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromString(deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[4]);
    /* 329 */       }
    /* 330 */       serializefromobject_isNull_34 = false;
    /* 331 */       serializefromobject_value_34 = serializefromobject_value_40;
    /* 332 */     }
    /* 333 */     if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 334 */       throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[19] /* errMsg */));
    /* 335 */     }
    /* 336 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_46 = true;
    /* 337 */     boolean serializefromobject_value_46 = false;
    /* 338 */     serializefromobject_argValue_4 = 4;
    /* 339 */
    /* 340 */     serializefromobject_isNull_46 = false;
    /* 341 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_46) {
    /* 342 */       serializefromobject_value_46 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(serializefromobject_argValue_4);
    /* 343 */     }
    /* 344 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_45 = false;
    /* 345 */     int serializefromobject_value_45 = -1;
    /* 346 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_46 && serializefromobject_value_46) {
    /* 347 */       serializefromobject_isNull_45 = true;
    /* 348 */       serializefromobject_value_45 = -1;
    /* 349 */     } else {
    /* 350 */       if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 351 */         throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[22] /* errMsg */));
    /* 352 */       }
    /* 353 */
    /* 354 */       if (false) {
    /* 355 */         throw QueryExecutionErrors.inputExternalRowCannotBeNullError();
    /* 356 */       }
    /* 357 */
    /* 358 */       if (serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(4)) {
    /* 359 */         throw new RuntimeException(((java.lang.String) references[21] /* errMsg */));
    /* 360 */       }
    /* 361 */
    /* 362 */       final Object serializefromobject_value_52 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.get(4);
    /* 363 */       int serializefromobject_value_51 = -1;
    /* 364 */       if (!false) {
    /* 365 */         if (serializefromobject_value_52 instanceof Integer) {
    /* 366 */           serializefromobject_value_51 = (Integer) serializefromobject_value_52;
    /* 367 */         } else {
    /* 368 */           throw new RuntimeException(serializefromobject_value_52.getClass().getName() + ((java.lang.String) references[20] /* errMsg */));
    /* 369 */         }
    /* 370 */       }
    /* 371 */       serializefromobject_isNull_45 = false;
    /* 372 */       serializefromobject_value_45 = serializefromobject_value_51;
    /* 373 */     }
    /* 374 */     if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 375 */       throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[23] /* errMsg */));
    /* 376 */     }
    /* 377 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_56 = true;
    /* 378 */     boolean serializefromobject_value_56 = false;
    /* 379 */     serializefromobject_argValue_5 = 5;
    /* 380 */
    /* 381 */     serializefromobject_isNull_56 = false;
    /* 382 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_56) {
    /* 383 */       serializefromobject_value_56 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(serializefromobject_argValue_5);
    /* 384 */     }
    /* 385 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_55 = false;
    /* 386 */     UTF8String serializefromobject_value_55 = null;
    /* 387 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_56 && serializefromobject_value_56) {
    /* 388 */       serializefromobject_isNull_55 = true;
    /* 389 */       serializefromobject_value_55 = ((UTF8String)null);
    /* 390 */     } else {
    /* 391 */       if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 392 */         throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[26] /* errMsg */));
    /* 393 */       }
    /* 394 */
    /* 395 */       if (false) {
    /* 396 */         throw QueryExecutionErrors.inputExternalRowCannotBeNullError();
    /* 397 */       }
    /* 398 */
    /* 399 */       if (serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(5)) {
    /* 400 */         throw new RuntimeException(((java.lang.String) references[25] /* errMsg */));
    /* 401 */       }
    /* 402 */
    /* 403 */       final Object serializefromobject_value_63 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.get(5);
    /* 404 */       java.lang.String serializefromobject_value_62 = null;
    /* 405 */       if (!false) {
    /* 406 */         if (serializefromobject_value_63 instanceof java.lang.String) {
    /* 407 */           serializefromobject_value_62 = (java.lang.String) serializefromobject_value_63;
    /* 408 */         } else {
    /* 409 */           throw new RuntimeException(serializefromobject_value_63.getClass().getName() + ((java.lang.String) references[24] /* errMsg */));
    /* 410 */         }
    /* 411 */       }
    /* 412 */       deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[5] = serializefromobject_value_62;
    /* 413 */
    /* 414 */       UTF8String serializefromobject_value_61 = null;
    /* 415 */       if (!false) {
    /* 416 */         serializefromobject_value_61 = org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromString(deserializetoobject_mutableStateArray_0[5]);
    /* 417 */       }
    /* 418 */       serializefromobject_isNull_55 = false;
    /* 419 */       serializefromobject_value_55 = serializefromobject_value_61;
    /* 420 */     }
    /* 421 */     if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 422 */       throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[27] /* errMsg */));
    /* 423 */     }
    /* 424 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_67 = true;
    /* 425 */     boolean serializefromobject_value_67 = false;
    /* 426 */     serializefromobject_argValue_6 = 6;
    /* 427 */
    /* 428 */     serializefromobject_isNull_67 = false;
    /* 429 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_67) {
    /* 430 */       serializefromobject_value_67 = serializefromobject_expr_0_0.isNullAt(serializefromobject_argValue_6);
    /* 431 */     }
    /* 432 */     boolean serializefromobject_isNull_66 = false;
    /* 433 */     UTF8String serializefromobject_value_66 = null;
    /* 434 */     if (!serializefromobject_isNull_67 && serializefromobject_value_67) {
    /* 435 */       serializefromobject_isNull_66 = true;
    /* 436 */       serializefromobject_value_66 = ((UTF8String)null);
    /* 437 */     } else {
    /* 438 */       if (serializefromobject_exprIsNull_0_0) {
    /* 439 */         throw new NullPointerException(((java.lang.String) references[30] /* errMsg */));
    /* 440 */       }
    /* 441 */
    /* 442 */       if (false) {
    /* 443 */         throw QueryExecutionErrors.inputExternalRowCannotBeNullError();
    /* 444 */       }

I have tried updating the Spark version to 3.3.2+ till 3.5 but the issue persists.
I'm not using any janino libraries externally. Janino version is 3.0.16 for spark 3.3.2.
